# How to wrap my Ruby on Rails condition around bootstrap accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, rubygems

I have the following conditions in my index page which I like to wrap in accordion.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% Category.top_level.each do |cat| %>
    <div><%= cat.name %></div> #=>This lists top level categories
    <ul>
      <% cat.lawyers.each do |law| %>
          <li>
            <%=  law.name %> #=>This lists lawyers under top level categories
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% cat.sub_categories.each do |subcat| %>
        <ul>
          <%= subcat.name %> #=>This lists corresponding subcategories under the top level categories
          <ul>
             <% subcat.lawyers.each do |law| %>
                 <li><%= law.name %></li> #=>This lists lawyers that are under corresponding subcategories
             <% end %>
          </ul>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**graphical view of my code and working correctly**

[image]

**what I like to do**

> I like to implement it with Bootstrap Accordion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this to display one panel for every top-level category and the lawyer list under them. If you want other sub-levels you can simply add another accordion inside the div class="panel-body". Remember to change properly ids of div class="panel-collapse" to make this work

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<% Category.top_level.each_with_index do |cat, index| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= index.to_s %>">
        <%= cat.name %> #=>This lists top level categories
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<%= index.to_s %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <ul>
          <% cat.lawyers.each do |law| %>
              <li>
                <%=  law.name %> #=>This lists lawyers under top level categories
              </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: other category level accordion didnt open. when I click them, it only take effect on the first category level. In other word, am unable to see what is in other categories.

Comment: Probably you are using the same id for panels, try to change them as I said  in my answer.(id=collapseX) for example